# Reverse order of words in pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column in python:

```
df
columnA
Apple Banana
Orange Citron Pineapple
```

How can I reserve the order of the substrings based on the white spaces? The outcome should be:

```
columnA
Banana Apple
Pineapple Citron Orange
```

Right now, I am only using:

```
df['columnA'] = df['columnA'].replace(r'(\s+).(\s+).(\s+)',r'\3\2\1',regex=True)
```

but this only works if I know the number of substrings, this I do not know upfront.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with a list comprehension for this task and avoid the `str` accessor

```
df['new'] = [' '.join(s.split()[::-1]) for s in df['columnA']]
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)
%timeit [' '.join(s.split()[::-1]) for s in df.col]
100 loops, best of 3: 12.9 ms per loop

%timeit df.col.str.split().apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x[::-1]))
10 loops, best of 3: 25.3 ms per loop

%timeit df.col.str.split().str[::-1].agg(' '.join)
10 loops, best of 3: 27.4 ms per loop

%timeit df.col.str.split().apply(reversed).apply(' '.join)
10 loop, best of 3: 28.7 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

The three steps you need are:

1. Split the string
2. Reverse the string
3. Join the string

The first and third steps can be achieved using [str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), so 
you could do:

```
 df.A.str.split().apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x[::-1]))
```

**Output**

```
0               Banana Apple
1    Pineapple Citron Orange
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Another alternative is to use [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
df.A.str.split().apply(reversed).apply(' '.join)
```